# SSRS - reduce the space between categories

Tags: reporting-services

I have tried to reduce the space between categories in my chart but until now have not succeeded. Also, I would like to hide those columns which have values = 0. Here is the image:

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Mary

Comment: What is the Interval on your Y axis?

Comment: Thanks for replying. The interval is "auto"

Comment: on the Horizontal Axis Properties change the Axis Type  to Scalar and remove "Always Include Zero". Not sure if it will fix this.. but worth a try